# Append Query String to htaccess PDF Redirect URL

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, redirect, append, url-parameters

I have PDF's that are available for download ONLY if people request a download key. All of that works perfectly. The problem is, if a person knows the URL to the PDF, they can access it directly. I want to block access to all the PDF's on my site while still allowing downloads. After days upon days of research and trial-and-error, I've come to believe that a redirect might be the best solution. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make anything work.

I created a sample subdomain to demonstrate the issue.

PDF URL: http://design.productivemotherhood.com/pdf/home-sellers-secrets-ebook.pdf

REDIRECT URL: http://design.productivemotherhood.com/index.php?msg=noKey

As you can see, I'm trying to redirect to the index while attaching a 'msg' parameter containing the message 'noKey'. It is important that this parameter be passed when the page redirects so that the index will display the error message.

The following statement will redirect the PDF's, but I can't figure out how to append the parameter to it.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.pdf) http://design.productivemotherhood.com/index.php
```

I've been looking for a solution for the past 3 days, but I just can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: Then your redirect destination should be `http://design.productivemotherhood.com/index.php?msg=noKey`

Comment: I've actually tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Do you get any errors?

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 (.pdf) http://design.productivemotherhood.com/index.php?msg=noKey` works as expected.  Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: So, you're saying that when you are redirected to http://design.productivemotherhood.com/index.php you are seeing the message "GET Message: noKey"? I've cleared my cache and all I see is the beginning, "GET Message: ", but there's no "noKey".

Comment: I just visited your links .it seems that your problem has been solved.

Comment: @starkeen You're right, it is finally working; with exactly the line of code you recommended. I cleared my browser cache several times yesterday and as of midnight, it still wasn't working. I'm really not sure why it's working today, but I'm glad it finally is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad it worked out. I have up voted your answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep people from directly accessing PDF documents on my website, I have setup a 301 redirect back to the site index. At the end of the redirect link, I've added a parameter so that when the index page loads, it will grab the GET variable and display a message for the user.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.pdf) http://design.productivemotherhood.com/index.php?msg=noKey
```

There must have been some kind of cache going on through my host that I didn't know to clear (because clearing my browser cache yesterday made no difference), but as of today, his solution is working.

Thanks to @starkeen for providing me with this solution, it's exactly what I needed.